# jQuery blur not working on iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, focus, blur

I've a simple textarea and if i focus on it using an iPad or iPhone the focus stay on that textarea until i click on another field or link. I want to remove the focus clicking on other elements and doing the same on a div with contenteditable attribute; so, as i read somewhere, i've tried this:

```
$('body').click(function(e) {
        if (!$('#text-to-change').is(e.target)) {
            $('#text-to-change').blur();
        } else {
            $('#text-to-change').focus();
        }
    });
```

It doesn't work... The focus stay there on that textarea.

Answer (score 1):

iOS not support focus and blur on mobile, for blur i have found one solution using CSS, if there is other solution, please write, it is interesting me

CSS:

```
// search input box blur support

//iPhone 6 in portrait & landscape
@media only screen
  and (min-device-width : 375px)
  and (max-device-width : 667px) {
    body { cursor: pointer; }
}

//iPhone 6 Plus in portrait & landscape
@media only screen
  and (min-device-width : 414px)
  and (max-device-width : 736px) {
    body { cursor: pointer; }
}

// iPhone 5 & 5S in portrait & landscape
@media only screen
  and (min-device-width : 320px)
  and (max-device-width : 568px) {

    body { cursor: pointer; }
}
```